# Grails FindAllWhere with Variables

Tags: variables, grails, hql, gsp

I am attempting to do a findAllWhere in a grails gsp passing in 2 variables: one that is the attribute and one that is the value I want that attribute to equal. I.E (author: Mark Twain) I cannot figure out the syntax and the error I am receiving does not help.

```
${Application.findAllWhere((${group1}): ${group})}
```

Group1 is a variable passed from the controller, and group is a variable from a g:each. Here is the error.

```
Error 500: 
Servlet: default
URI: /archetype/application/applicationPortfolio/GroupLangTechOwn  
Exception Message: No signature of method:
C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp.$() is  
applicable for argument types: 
(C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp$_run_closure2_closure56_closure144) values: [C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp$_run_closure2_closure56_closure144@239dbdd6] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure) 
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp.$() is applicable for argument types: (C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp$_run_closure2_closure56_closure144) values: [C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp$_run_closure2_closure56_closure144@239dbdd6] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure) 
Class: applicationPortfolio.gsp 
At Line: [631]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also getting this error: not sure why it changed.    Exception Message: startup failed: C__projects_Archetype_grails_app_views_application_applicationPortfolio_gsp: 280: unexpected token: printHtmlPart @ line 280, column 1. printHtmlPart(77) ^ 1 error

Comment: Where are the 2 variables coming from?  I don't think you need to put them between `${}` when the entire method call is already between a set of `${}`.  Try just `${Application.findAllWhere((group1): group)}`.  Probably don't need the `()` around `group1` either.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue - don't do database calls from a GSP. This isn't PHP ffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simplifying to: `${Application.findAllWhere(group: group)}` as Weezle indicated

But it is typically better to put this in the controller and return eg:

```
class MyContoller {

def myAction() {
   [appList: Application.findAllWhere(group: group)]
}

myAction.gsp 

${appList}

<g:each var="app" in="${appList}">
  ${app.id} -  ${app.name}
</g:each>
```